# starting a new layout on clicking image button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have following code that should open a new layout(.xml file) on clicking an `ImageButton`.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.board_play);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

But I get an error in onClick method. Help what could I change to remove the error. Am I using correct implementation to change the layout using an ImageButton?

Comment: Remove super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); from onClick

Comment: @AnswerBot thank you. It cleared the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting different layouts to the same activity is bad design. Every Activity has a life cycle and should have just one layout set to the activity.

Instead start a new Activity and set `board_play` to the same.

Use

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BoardActivity.class));
    }
```

In BoardActivity

```
 public class BoardActivity extends Activity
 {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.board_play);
 }
```

Make sure you make an entry for BoarActivity in manifest file.

You can also use fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I will use multiple linear layout or/and any container that you want, control the visibility attribute instead of `setContentView`.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a new `Class`** 
For example `MainActivity2.java`

```
public class MainActivity2   extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.board_play);
}

}
```

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** dont forget to add

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity2"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Your code should now look like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
          startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```